# scanner cannot be resolved to a type error found in my program

Tags: java

```java
package scanfFunctionInJava;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerType {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("your entered value is = " +x);



    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Can you update your question with Exception/log!

Comment: Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) --> you have used new scanner - S needs to be in caps

Comment: Java **is** case sensitive....

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
Scanner sc = new scanner(System.in);
```

**S**canner versus **s**scanner. Java is case sensitive, and the type you intend to use is named **S**canner, not scanner.

In programming, each and any character matters. And the error message probably tells you that **scanner** is unknown.

Thus the real answer is: carefully read the error messages, and then look out for such subtle issues.

Comment: I would add that Java is case sensitive.... not all programming languages are (e.g. Fortran, Pascal, ABAP, as I remember)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Yes, it is always better to be explicit about such things. Reworked the answer, thanks for your input!

Comment: anyway the important message is the last sentence [:-)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Honestly, that last sentence is the main reason I decided to write this up as *answer*.